# Perl symmetric difference aka disjunctive union of two sets

Tags: perl

I have two sets,

```
@ a=(2,5,3)@ B=(3,4,1), I want to get (2,5,4,1)
```

Whether the output is a newline, a space, or a comma is not important

My idea is:

```
Intersection @ c=(2,5,3,4,1), union @ d=(3), result: @ c - @ d=(2,5,4,1)
```

Is there a more elegant solution (I don't like to install additional modules)

Comment: *(I don't like to install additional modules)* Why do you like to make things harder than they have to be? https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Scalar

Answer (score 8):

While I duly note the question's premise

> I don't like to install additional modules

I would still like to demonstrate the utility of libraries. With [Set::Scalar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Scalar)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Set::Scalar;

my @ary1 = (2,5,3);
my @ary2 = (3,4,1);

# "want to get (2,5,4,1)"; like union - intersection

my $s1 = Set::Scalar->new(@ary1);
my $s2 = Set::Scalar->new(@ary2);

my $u = $s1->union($s2);

my $i = $s1->intersection($s2);

my $res = $u - $i; 

say $res;

# Or just
my $symm_diff = $s1->symmetric_difference($s2);
say $symm_diff;
```

Prints a  `(1 2 4 5)` line, twice.

This particular set operation is called [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), and the library has it as well as shown at the end.  There is a whole lot more that this library can do; this is just basic stuff.

There is also the related [Set::Object](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Object), with a different slant, but also with all methods as above (including the `symmetric_difference`) for directly answering this need.

Out of list-manipulation libraries I'd mention [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare), which also directly resolves this question and has a lot more.

Comment: Thanks, was trying to find the proper name (since no results were coming up for "cross union". I'll edit the title of the question so it can more easily be found

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I couldn't remember at first either -- thanks for updating the question with it

Answer (score 7):

Using a hash is the easiest way to represent a set (the keys are the members of the set, and the value can mean anything; often `undef` is used). Here's some code (could be more compact):

```perl
@a = (2,5,3);
@b = (3,4,1);

foreach $val ( @a ) { $d{$val} |= 1 };
foreach $val ( @b ) { $d{$val} |= 2 };
foreach $val ( keys(%d) ) {
    push(@result, $val) if $d{$val} != 3;
}
print(join(",", @result));
```

We are using two bits in the values of `%d` to represent membership in each set, and skipping values that are in both sets.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
my %s;
$s{ $_ } |= 1 for @a;  # Sets bit 0 for elements of set @a
$s{ $_ } |= 2 for @b;  # Sets bit 1 for elements of set @b

my @union   =                        keys %s;  # One or two bits set
my @isect   = grep { $s{ $_ } == 3 } keys %s;  # Both bits set
my @symdiff = grep { $s{ $_ } != 3 } keys %s;  # Only one bit set
```

If you want just the symmetric difference, this should be faster:

```perl
my %a; @a{ @a } = (); delete @a{ @b };
my %b; @b{ @b } = (); delete @b{ @a };
my @symdiff = ( keys( %a ), keys( %b ) );
```