# How to find if an array has a value not found in list

Tags: perl

I have array `@hon_data`. If any elements of the array are one of a known list of values, I return zero.

```
for my $hon_field (@hon_data) {
    if($hon_field ne 'B' and $hon_field ne 'S' and $hon_field ne 'G' and 
      $hon_field ne 'D' and $hon_field ne 'L') {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

The number of values to check is growing, so this approach is getting complicated to manage. Is there a way to do this with the values in an array?

```
my @results =("B","G","S","D","N","L");
my @results2 = ("A","G","S","D","N","L");

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @_;
}

my @unique = uniq(@results, @results2);
```

In result2 A is unique value and it should return A only But this code is not working.

Comment: Are these sets (no repeated values)? If so, then what you want is called [symmetric difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74148140/589924)

Comment: @ikegami I have a fixed array let's say array1 and there is an array2 coming from user . If any value which is coming from user is not in array1 we need to report that .

Comment: I would think using hashes would be a super fast solution instead of arrays. See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/perl-cookbook/1565922433/ch05s12.html

Comment: Sounds more like a normal set difference, not symmetric difference.

Comment: @Shawn yes I agree with you not sure why everyone thinks it is symmetric

Comment: I voted to reopen but nobody else has so far (there's probably a *different*, more appropriate question this should be closed as a duplicate of afterwards...)

Comment: Re "*not sure why everyone thinks it is symmetric*", You were talking bout unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking how to replace the hardcoded loop with a dynamic one. The following is one way this could be done:

```perl
for my $hon_field ( @hon_data ) {
   for my $ok (qw( B S G D L )) {
      if ( $hon_field ne $ok ) {
         return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

That is a lot better. But if the elements are strings, the inner loop can be replaced with a hash lookup.

```perl
my %ok = map { $_ => 1 } qw( B S G D L );

for my $hon_field ( @hon_data ) {
   if ( !$ok{ $hon_field } ) {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

This can also be written as follows:

```perl
use List::Util qw( any );

my %ok = map { $_ => 1 } qw( B S G D L );

return 0 if any { !$ok{$_} } @hon_data;
```

A similar approach can be used to find the difference of sets.

```perl
my %ok = map { $_ => 1 } qw( B S G D L );;

my @diff = grep { !$ok{ $_ } } @hon_data;    # diff = hon_data - { B, S, G, D, L }
```